# What is is an "M7" Diode

Tags: arduino, diodes, eaglecad

I know what it is in general terms of course. But I mean specifically what does the M7 mean. I certainly can't just go to digikey and order an M7 diode because such a part does not exist. I'm making a rugged arduino clone (using kicad) for my own use and intend to put a fuse or possibly resettable fuse in front of that diode so as it doesn't burn out etc... so I have thought of that.

It appears to indicate that the diode must have a 1000v reverse voltage.

See here for the circuit (see the external power supply circuit):
http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-leonardo-schematic_3b.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a SMT version of a 1N4007 (1A 1000V PIV). They definitely exist (I have a reel of a similar type kicking around somewhere) and they are very popular in Asia (typically from suppliers that are lesser known in the West).

You can use any 1A rectifier of sufficient voltage rating that comes in a DO-214AC (SMA) package.

[image]

Edit:

I had a look at the schematic- the purpose of that diode on the input is to short out a reverse-polarity input. Diodes are pretty rugged and tend to fail short, so unless the source is something like a car battery or PC power supply, there's a good chance it won't fry the board. 50V rating is more than enough for this part- the NCP1117S is only good for 20V in (abs max).

Comment: I have always thought such diodes were used as user-input voltage protection, but with a PIV of 1000V it must be that these are rather for ESD protection.

Comment: With a PIV of 1000V and an If of 1A, surely these are more power supply rectifiers (a la 1N4007) than anything else.

Comment: @EMFields Yup, and across relay coils. There is little (if any) price premium for higher voltage though, like their 1N400x cousins. As I said in my edit, that one is (shunt) reverse polarity protection. There's no reason to have it rated more than 50V PIV.

Comment: Oops... I was writing to @sherrellbc and forgot to address the comment; sorry 'bout that. Another thing I like about the family is the Vf(max) of 1V at If = 1A regardless of PIV.

Comment: Note that they are relatively slow, with several microseconds reverse recovery time.

Comment: @starblue Yes, trr is big, like a 1N400x. Presumably the M7 can be pressed into service as a poor man's (or woman's) PIN diode.

Comment: Yes, certainly widely available with lots of sellers on alibaba/aliexpress e.g 1000 for $7! http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-1000pcs-lot-1N4007-M7-SMA-DO-214AC-1A-1000V-SMD-Rectifler-diodes/2024510994.html

Comment: Here's a datasheet that shows trr = 1500ns --> freq response = 666.7kHz for the M7: http://diotec.com/tl_files/diotec/files/pdf/datasheets/m1.pdf. This is *significantly* better than a 1N4007 (https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/pdf/microcircuits/students/diode/1n4004-general.pdf), which has a trr = 30us --> freq response = 33.3kHz. Therefore, a 1N4007 diode is 20x *slower* than an M7 diode. So, even though the M7 is by no means a fast diode, it is nowhere near as slow as the 1N400x series either.